# ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN - Firebase Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to delete user from Firebase but it returns a `PlatformException` (Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN, This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request., null)
)
I've tried `reauthenticateWithCredential` as well.

```
 new FlatButton(
                child: Text("Delete"),
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    FirebaseUser user =
                        await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
                    var credential = EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(
                        email: user.email, password: "Password");
                    user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
                    user.delete();
                  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
                    print("///////// ${e.code}");//This is not working, And should work cause WRONG_PASSSWORD errors.
                  } catch (e) {
                    print("Deletion error $e");
                    showInSnackBar("Something went wrong");
                  }
                },
              ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error:

> ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN, This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication

Means that you should call `reauthenticateWithCredential`, since `reauthenticateWithCredential` returns a `Future<AuthResult>` then you have to do the following:

```
var result = await user.reauthenticateWithCredential(credential);
await result.user.delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
AuthResult result = await firebaseUser.reauthenticateWithCredential(
                          EmailAuthProvider.getCredential(email: email, password: password));
result.user.delete();
```